# How to convert this into mp4 file?

Tags: javascript, html, mp4

I found some awesome video in some site but I can only download in html file(frame source)
I want to convert it into .MP4 So I'll leave a code below.
I Search on internet (Quora) It can't convert the file.
How can I convert it!!!!!
(I need the file in school project)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- NREUM: (1) -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <!-- change title to match the h1 heading -->
    <title>Creative Cloud Player (HLS-everywhere Player)</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/wna4qxf.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/ingest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.2.5/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/videojs-media-sources.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/ccv-betaplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/js/VisitorAPI.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            overflow: hidden
        }
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            display: block;
            font-family: adobe-clean, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute
        }
    </style>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        window.ccv$serverData = { "status": "ok", "rootDir": "https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv", "duration": 18.767, "settings_json": "json/behance/config.json", "strings_json": "json/behance/en.json", "ccvid": "ESYZSxw9MWb", "clientid": "behance", "language": "en", "debug": "false", "posterframe": "https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/image/ESYZSxw9MWb_poster.jpg?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7", "seriesthumbnail_sprite_url": "https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/image/ESYZSxw9MWb_sprite_0.jpg?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7", "thumbnail_per_sprite": 50, "total_number_of_sprites": 1, "series_thumbnail_frequency": 2, "series_thumbnail_width": 160, "series_thumbnail_height": 106, "displayThumbnails": true, "wwwhost": "https://www-ccv.adobe.io/v1/player/ccv/ESYZSxw9MWb?api_key=behance1", "m3u8URL": "https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/master.m3u8?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7", "mp4URL": "https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/ESYZSxw9MWb_576.mp4?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7", "inputHeight": 1080, "inputWidth": 1620, "playCountBeacon": { "url": "https://www-ccv.adobe.io/v1/player/ccv/ESYZSxw9MWb/firstplay", "type": "POST", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Api-Key": "behance1" }, "data": { "nonce": "C51rfhs+JKrNuSSRDgiqHL17+no=" } }, "playCountBeaconRetry": 1, "strings": { "%press_esc": "Press Esc to exit full screen mode.", "%error_has_occurred": "Sorry, there was a problem loading this video.", "%error_has_occurred_sub": "Please try refreshing the page.", "%conversion_in_progress": "We’re preparing your video.", "%conversion_in_progress_sub": "This page will refresh automatically when it’s ready. Or, check back shortly to see it.", "%invalid_video": "Sorry, we can’t find the video you’re looking for.", "%invalid_video_sub": "Please check that the URL was typed correctly. Or, the video may have been removed.", "%bad_video": "Sorry, we couldn’t prepare this video for playback.", "%bad_video_sub": "Please try uploading the video again. If that doesn’t help, there may be a probem with the file.", "%reload_video": "We’re almost done preparing your video.", "%reload_video_sub": "This page will refresh automatically when it’s ready. Or, check back shortly to see it.", "%removed_video": "This video no longer exists.", "%removed_video_sub": "Sorry, the video you’re looking for has been removed.", "%enable_flash_player": "Sorry, there was a problem loading this video.", "%enable_flash_player_sub": "Please try refreshing the page." }, "settings": { "COMMENTS": "The format of this file MUST match the definitions in ccv-player.d.ts. For validation use http://jsonlint.com.", "brightcove": { "bcid": "2679128769001", "playerid": "2727268340001", "playerkey": "AQ~~,AAACb7Se6nk~,ee7RfT0WJHLewwaRq30kZmTGY507rmYu", "rootdir": "", "theme": "default" }, "debugging": { "debug": "false", "log_info": "true", "log_warn": "true", "log_debug": "true", "log_error": "true" }, "client": { "bgcolor": "#FFFFFF" } }, "minframeWidth": 864, "minframeHeight": 576 };
    </script>
    <link href="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv/css/ccv-player.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<video id="video-js"  preload="none" class="video-js" data-poster="https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/image/ESYZSxw9MWb_poster.jpg?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7"
       data-seriesthumbnail_sprite_url="https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/image/ESYZSxw9MWb_sprite_0.jpg?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7" data-series_thumbnail_frequency="2"
       data-series_thumbnail_width="160" data-series_thumbnail_height="106"
       data-thumbnail_per_sprite="50" data-total_number_of_sprites="1"
       data-status="ok" data-rootdir="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/build293a76c166/resource/ccv" data-duration="18.767" data-displayThumbnails="true"
       data-environ="embed" data-settings_json="json/behance/config.json" data-strings_json="json/behance/en.json" data-secure="true"
       data-ccvid="ESYZSxw9MWb" data-clientid="behance" data-mediatoken="st=1606801217~exp=1607060417~acl=/shared_assets/image/*!/z/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/*!/i/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/*!/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/*!/ESYZSxw9MWb/image/*~hmac=22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7"
       data-wwwhost="https://www-ccv.adobe.io/v1/player/ccv/ESYZSxw9MWb?api_key=behance1" data-inputWidth="1620" data-inputHeight="1080" data-debug="false" data-env="prod"
       data-clientappname="behance" src="">
    <source src="https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/master.m3u8?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    <source src="https://adobeprod-a.akamaihd.net/ESYZSxw9MWb/rend/ESYZSxw9MWb_576.mp4?hdnea=st%3D1606801217%7Eexp%3D1607060417%7Eacl%3D%2Fshared_assets%2Fimage%2F*%21%2Fz%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2Fi%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Frend%2F*%21%2FESYZSxw9MWb%2Fimage%2F*%7Ehmac%3D22af373ac66fc0d0d96f4d16ab4d7ff2994937881d4afde4f3a2d098f2e91ac7" type="video/mp4">

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the original url of the video ?

Comment: Sure! Here is original link !!!!! https://www.behance.net/gallery/54944623/Twitch-Livestream-Designs-%28Stream-PackagesOverlays%29

Comment: the best way to download videos is using the devtools in your browser and using to toggle as device, i upload the file your need here http://www.mediafire.com/file/pe7woll050erjon/ESYZSxw9MWb_576.mp4/file

Answer (score 0):

Looks at the `<video>` element. Inside it, look at the second `<source>` element:

```
<source src="....." type="video/mp4">
```

This is the `mp4` video source.

Where I've put the dots you can see an URL - paste that into your web browser's address bar and you'll get the video to download. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I think so. But this source code is Frame source video. Is there an way to download Frame video into mp4?

Comment: Or is there an html video to mp4?